# Trying to write a query with LIKE and a variable with content

Tags: android

```
int FROMcountryChooseId=10;
String ToConvert = (EditView)findViewById(R.id.NumberEditView); 
String query="SELECT DISTINCT trim(Country.Country) FROM Country,DCI WHERE Country.CountryN°= "+FROMcountryChooseId+ " AND Country.Country LIKE "+"'&ToConvert&'"+" AND DCI._ID=Medicaments.DCIN° ORDER BY DRUG ASC LIMIT 1000;";

myDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)
```

Hi i don't know how to make my query recognize wordToConvert as variable that content something and not just a String.

Any idea how to do that??

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) to perform proper string substitutions.

```
sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(
          "SELECT DISTINCT trim(Country.Country)
                     FROM Country,DCI
                    WHERE Country.CountryN°= ?
                      AND Country.Country LIKE ?
                      AND DCI._ID=Medicaments.DCIN°
                    ORDER BY DRUG ASC
                    LIMIT 1000",
          new String[] {
              Integer.toString(FROMcountryChooseId),
              "%" + ToConvert + "%"
          });
```

Just place a `?` where your literals go, and set the corresponding value in the string array.  Android will properly escape and quote the value, so you do not need to pre-process it in any way.

In this case, a `LIKE` expression is just a literal like any other.

Note that semicolons are not needed here, as multiple statements are not supported.

Comment: its work for a simple query what to do with a more complete query like what i just update. thank you for you help!!!!

Comment: @dirko, updated.  Same idea, just using two literals instead of one.  Do you really use the `°` in your field names?  How do you type that?

Comment: I just receive the database from a client can't change it,No idea how to type i just copy :) ,i have a problem the FROMcountryChooseId it's int   and the array is String.

Comment: Just use `.toString()`.  I've updated the answer.  `rawQuery` binds everything as a string, but SQLite is loosely-typed, so it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for you help and advice!!!,but FROMcountryChooseId.toString() is not legal,Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type int. its possible with String.valueOf(FROMcountryChooseId)